# SharePoint - Automation of Unfollowing Deleted Sites and Documents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Upon deletion of a site or document, I'd like the site/document to be deleted from everyone's "follow" list.  However, it appears that is not happening.  I've confirmed the "Activity Feed Timer Job" is functioning normally.

This is SP On Prem 2013

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself. The best way to do so by using event receivers. You have to check each user on the user profile and unfollow the item if they are following it.

For sites, you can use [SPWebEventReceiver.SiteDeleting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.sitedeleting?view=sharepoint-server) and for documents [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemDeleting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemdeleting?view=sharepoint-server).